# Generic parameter: How to check type

Tags: vb.net, generics

If I have the following function:

```
Private Function AddObject(Of T As MyBaseClass)(pos As PointF, sz As SizeF) As T
End Function
```

How can I check the type of `T` inside the function? For example I have 3 classes that inherit from `MyBaseClass` namely `Shape`, `Label` and `Rect`. I tried the following two versions:

```
If T Is Rect Then
If TypeOf T Is Rect Then
```

but both produce errors. What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: `T` is a type placeholder, where is the parameter for an object of type T which is being added?

Comment: @Plutonix: I don't have any parameter of type T; it is just the function return type that I want to make generic.

Comment: then how are you to know in that procedure which type to create/return??

Comment: Do you want to check for that *exact* type, or for any type which is `Rect` or a subclass?

Comment: @Plutonix: Because it's a generic type parameter...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Rect doesn't have any subclasses in my system. I just want to distinguish between Rect, Label and Shape. I expect it to be called for example like `AddObject(Of Rect)(pos, size)` and then inside `AddObject` I want to create a Rect object based on T and return it.

Comment: @dotNET: It may not have any now, but how do you want your method to behave if you *do* have any subclasses? That will affect the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: mmmm...tricky to answer, but I guess I'll want it to create most-specific type object. For example, if I have `BlueRect` and `GreenRect` classes inheriting from `Rect`, I'll want it to create `BlueRect` when I send that as generic parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need an *exact* match you can use:

```
GetType(T) Is GetType(Rect)
```

If you want to match with inheritance, you can use:

```
GetType(Rect).IsAssignableFrom(GetType(T))
```

Although to be honest, if you have to handle each subclass separately, it doesn't feel like an ideal kind of generic method. Can you not add an abstract method in the base class and implement it in each subclass instead?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a bunch. And no, I cannot do it in the base class becuz AddObject is not required in that hierarchy, but in a different place.